# Qt5 installation problems

Tags: macos, qt, installation, osx-lion, qt5

I am trying to install Qt5 on OS-X 10.7.5, using the [prebuilt binary version](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/qt-mac-opensource-5.0.0-clang-offline.dmg).

Everything seems to be OK, QtCreator is installed and it works.

However when I create a new project, I get the error: "No valid kit found". The Qt version detected seems to be the old Qt4 one only.

The file I used for the installation is the one that contains everything: Qt5, QtCreator, ... (398 MB), but when installed only the directory with QtCreator seems to be available.

Should I uninstall Qt4 first?
Is it a problem anybody else had?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt Creator 2.6 introduced the concept of "Kits." You need to have at least one kit properly configured with a Qt version and tool chain. Unfortunately, the SDK install doesn't configure the kit for you and the documentation is just outright lacking.

Here's some information on how to setup a kit. The page is not even linked from the main doc pages.
http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html

Comment: Your link is a 404

Answer (score 0):

In QtCreator, you can set the location of the Qt SDK you want to use.

See [this guide](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-project-qmake.html) at the official website.